# Extract dollar amount in sheets text cell

Tags: google-sheets, search, filter, numbers, extract

Ideally what I'm looking for is to get the dollar amount extracted no matter the format.

[image: Desired]

Sheet link: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1drTPlnQmVTsbUXwJDfQr7DnHjSbnGx-fLthad6KxfM8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete everything from Column B, including the header. Then place the following formula in cell B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header"; IF(A2:A="",,VALUE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\$(\d+\.?\d*)"))))})`

You may change the header text within the formula as you like.

If a cell in A2:A is blank, the corresponding cell in B2:B will be left blank as well.

Otherwise `REGEXEXTRACT` will look for a pattern that begins with a literal dollar sign. The parenthesis within the quotes denote the beginning and end of a capture group (i.e., what will be returned if found) following that literal dollar sign. The pattern `\d+\.?\d*` means "a group of one or more digits, followed by zero or one literal period symbols, followed by zero or more digits."

`IFERROR` will cause null to be rendered instead of an error if such a pattern is not able to be extracted.

`VALUE` will convert the extracted string (or null) to a real number.

If you would prefer that null be returned instead of `0` where no pattern match is found, you can use the following variation of the formula instead:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header"; IFERROR(VALUE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\$(\d+\.?\d*)"),"x")))})`

If your strings may include numbers with comma separators, use the following versions of the above two formulas, respectively:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header V1"; IF(A2:A="",,VALUE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,",",""),"\$(\d+\.?\d*)"))))})`

`=ArrayFormula({"Header V2"; IFERROR(VALUE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,",",""),"\$(\d+\.?\d*)"),"x")))})`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\$(\d+.\d+|\d+)")*1))
```

[image]